# Mensaje de sweet alert desaparece muy rapido

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

Al dar click al botón, aparece la ventana del SweetAlert con el mensaje, pero desaparece en seguida no permite que el usuario lea la alerta.

**Script:**

```
<script type="Text/javascript">
    function Notificacion2() {
        swal({
            type: 'error',
            title: 'La contraseña es incorrecta',
            showConfirmButton: false
        })
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usa el parámetro "`timer:`" el cual permite definir el tiempo que demorara en desaparecer la alerta.

```
<script type="Text/javascript">
        function Notificacion2() {
            swal({
                type: 'error',
                title: 'La contraseña es incorrecta',
                showConfirmButton: false,
                timer: 3000 // es ms (mili-segundos)
            })
        }
    </script>
```

> Esto funciona desde **Sweetalert 2**

Answer (score 0):

Si estás usando AJAX no olvides de agregar al submit el `*e.preventDefault();*`, así elimina que recargue la página y pueda seguir procesando tu solicitud de AJAX.